# How to do case-insensitive search in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

How to do case-insensitive search in azure search?

My `index` contains `Etc.` if I search with `ETC` using fuzzy search i cant get result back. I think its for `case sensitivity`. How to do `case-insensitive` search?

Comment: Text is analyzed at index and query time, which by default removes punctuation and normalizes everything to lowercase, so case is not the reason your query doesn’t match. Can you please edit your question to provide more details about the exact request you’re sending and the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

If you use an equivalent of `$filter=city eq 'amsterdam'` it will not match "Amsterdam" since filtering is case-sensitive. In this case you could use `$filter=search.ismatch('amsterdam', 'city')`. But then your `city` field must be defined als searchable and not simply filterable.

Comment: The problem comes when the city has 2 words.  Like `$filter=search.ismatch('red bluff', 'city')`.  This query will find everything with a word `red` and everything with `bluff`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [latest comment](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328673-support-case-insensitive-comparison-in-filters) in this thread, it is not supported by Azure Search so far.

You could vote up that for prioritize.